# How to add automatic slideshow for sharepoint online modern pages

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, modern-experience, carousel

So I am a SharePoint administrator and have been working with SharePoint for a while.

So I initially have been able create auto slideshows on modern pages which changes on interval but recently I cant find that functionality on any of the web-parts.

I have tried highlighted content and image gallery with carousel layout but there is no option to cycle images on intervals as used to. I have searched everywhere on the web and no one seems to be talking about it. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

[image: Look at this image below.. cant find the option to cycle pictures]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my understanding, automatic slideshow is not supported in OOTB Image Gallery web-part as of now.

However you can develop a custom web part using [SharePoint Framework](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/sharepoint-framework-overview).

There are already developed samples for the same. Check below references.

**References**:

1. [React Carousel Web Part](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-carousel).
2. [SharePoint Framework - React-based Carousel](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/sharepoint-framework-react-based-carousel2/).

Answer (score 1):

Use the Image gallery web part to share collections of pictures on a page. Select your images with the file picker or drag them onto the web part.

With the Tiles layout, you can choose an aspect ratio (1:1,16:9, or 4:3), and you can drag and drop images within the web part to reorder them.

With the Carousel layout, you can set whether to automatically cycle through images, and the speed at which to cycle. You cannot reorder images in this layout.

For more information, refer this link,

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-the-image-gallery-web-part-bbcbe560-14a7-4369-8ef5-3255845e3bfd

Comment: This is the problem, there is no option for cycling images in the web-part edit option

Comment: As @karthik implies, you have to select Carousel layout to see that option, it is not available in the other layouts.

Comment: Hello @willman look at the screenshot above that shows me selecting the carousel layout. There is no option for cycling between images